# Force rerun of subscribe in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have one question. So, I want to publish only one object from collection to user and when user finish using that data I want him to rerun subscribe and get new object to work on. How should I do that? I am storing that one object in users minimongo because when user gets that object it becomes unavailable.

Comment: while the user is using that 1 object, is it possible changes to it will be published from the server?

Comment: what do you mean by "finish using that data"? by default, a `subscribe` will listen to changes to that collection on the server. if by "finish using the data" means that some changes are made, the user will automatically get that new data.

Comment: No, user gets data and when do something with it, data dissapears because method ,,invalidate" removes that data from publication. So ussr had 1 object and now has 0 but I need it to get new 1 object from publication.

Comment: You can use [tracker-autorun](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html). Inside the auto-run, you have to re-subscribe every time the object is unavailable . You should use a session or reactive-var variable to make the auto-run reactive. so, if you set your object to that session/reactive var, it will automatically re-run every time the value of that variable change.

Comment: Ok, I've tryed autorun but without reactiveVar. I'll try it, thank you!

Comment: I've tried this, it's not helping. :/

Comment: @Dale12, you need to show your code. publish, subscribe, and the method call code that invalidates.

Answer (score 0):

So, if this helps for anyone:

Just stop subscription with handler.stop() and then subscribe again!